# Application.OnTime seems to conflict with manually started subs

Tags: vba, excel

I've made a workbook what has to be closed after 10 minutes of inactivity. I use a timer with Application.OnTime. I use the Application.OnTime command after every minute of inactivity, to refresh a message in the statusbar. In the last minute I use the Application.OnTime command after every second of inactivity to speed up the messages in the statusbar.
This works well, so far so good.

```
Public dtNextTime As Date
Public lngWaitTime As Long
Public lngRefreshTime As Long

Sub StartCountDownTimer()

    Call StopCountDownTimer

    dtNextTime = 0
    lngWaitTime = 1 * 60 ' In my real workbook, the user can change the 10 minutes in a cell and I use this value in this sub

    ' Set initial RefreshTime
    lngRefreshTime = 60

    Call PlanNextTime

End Sub

Sub PlanNextTime()

    Dim strWaitTime As String
    Dim lngShowWaitTime As Long

    If lngWaitTime >= 60 Then
        lngShowWaitTime = lngWaitTime / 60
    Else
        lngShowWaitTime = lngWaitTime
    End If

    Select Case lngWaitTime
        Case Is >= 120
            strWaitTime = " minutes"
        Case Is >= 60
            strWaitTime = " minute"
        Case Is > 1
            strWaitTime = " seconds"
        Case Is = 1
            strWaitTime = " second"
    End Select

    Application.StatusBar = "If you don't use this workbook it will be closed in " & lngShowWaitTime & strWaitTime

    If lngWaitTime <= 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Workbook is being closed"
        Call CloseWorkbook
    Else

        If dtNextTime = 0 Then dtNextTime = Now()

        If lngWaitTime > 60 Then
            lngRefreshTime = 60
        Else
            lngRefreshTime = 1
        End If

        Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dtNextTime, Procedure:="PlanNextTime", Schedule:=True
        dtNextTime = dtNextTime + TimeSerial(0, 0, lngRefreshTime)

        lngWaitTime = lngWaitTime - lngRefreshTime

    End If

End Sub

Sub StopCountDownTimer()

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dtNextTime, Procedure:="PlanNextTime", Schedule:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub

Sub CloseWorkbook()


' In my real workbook, at this place I call a sub to do some final things like saving the workbook
Application.StatusBar = False
ThisWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

To test this, I used only the last minute. Then I found out I get strange problems with other manually started procedures. My preliminary conclusion: you can't run a manually started procedure together the a procedure started with the Application.OnTime command. I think I can find a workaround, but I want to be sure my conclusion is right. Excel VBA should be single-threaded, so I'm not sure my conclusion is right.

Therefore my question to you: is someone familiar with problems with procedures fired with the Application.OnTime command, fired on the same time a manual started procedure is running?
Do you know any way to deal with this issue?

Comment: You want the `PlanNextTime()` to run, even if another routine is currently running?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that the `Event` you've created doesn't fire when an existing routine is running. That would be correct for the reason you surmised: Excel VBA is single-threaded.

Perhaps your 'manually started' procedure is amending records in a large table for instance or similar? If that's the case, insert a `DoEvents` into your loops to allow any pending events scheduled to be fired. This will cause the running to jump to your scheduled subroutine (`PlanNextTime()`) and complete that before returning to your loop.

I can't see much wrong with your posted code, though I confess I've not gone through it entirely to check your clever but confusing minutes vs seconds handling. I did notice however that you don't appear to be calling `StopCountDownTimer()` within your `CloseWorkbook()`. This will likely mean that on closing the workbook, or even Excel entirely, Excel will re-open the Workbook after closing to run your next scheduled event.